# PYTHON: How search list by index number?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

example: my_list(1) = 10.0 (is there a way to do this?)

```
my_list = list(1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 10000.0)
```

I'm trying to create a for loop that prints each index separately, so basically I want to cycle through each index and print it

Comment: You can use `enumerate()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the non-Pythonic way

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate over it:

```
for element in my_list:
    print(element)
```

If you want to print the indices as well, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
    print(index, element)
```